# Image over an opacity background is picking up opacity as well

Tags: opacity

I made the container of a website have an opacity: 0.8 and then when I add a photo in this container, and actually anything, it also shows up as the same opacity.  I'd like to keep images at 100% with no opacity.  I am unsure how this actually would be fixed. I've tried changing the image z-index and opacity specifically but that didn't work.  Any help would be great.  See the sample below.

[View Sample](http://www.birdbathgroup.com/template-happenings.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off making the background of these elements semi-transparent, rather than adding transparency to the entire container.  This would not affect the photo and would make the text and buttons easier to read.

Comment: Thanks.  I can change some of the element backgrounds, but there are large gaps where the content box isn't complete. What if I created a background image that was transparent and repeated it?

Comment: That would certainly work, and has the benefit of working on IE7 and IE8, which do not support either the opacity property or RGBA background colors.

Comment: The background images worked, but tried the RBGA first, which was awesome. But you're right, IE8 didn't render very well.  Thanks again for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the explanations e.g. on http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ :

> We have long had the opacity property, which is similar, but opacity
>   forces all decendant elements to also become transparent and there is
>   no way to fight it

So you have to use e.g.:

```
background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
```